# Unity: How to get the metadata tag of a leaderboard score in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

I've been looking everywhere for this, apparently Google forgot about getting the metadata tags associated with a leaderboard score.

In their [Official Github unity plugin Documentation](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity), they clearly stated:

> To post a score and include a metadata tag use the Play Game Services instance directly:

[image]

And this worked just great, **but now after a lot of searching i think that there is no way that you can get this Metadata Tag back from the leaderboard!.**

Also from the official documentation:

You can load scores from a leaderboard using this function:

```
PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.LoadScores(lId,
            leaderboardStart,
            scoresToDisplay,
            leaderboardType,
            leaderboardTimeSpan,
            (LeaderboardScoreData data) => {
               for (int i = 0; i < data.Scores.Length; i++)
               {
                   IScore score = data.Scores[i];

                   //handle where you want to save the scores
               }

});
```

Can anyone help about how to get the score metadata tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out, for anyone who's trying to do what i wanted, here's the solution:

First you have to assign a metadata tag to the score that you want to report like this:

```
public void ReportScoreToLeaderboard(string leaderboardId, int score)
{
    PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.ReportScore(score, leaderboardId, "SantaCharacter", (bool success) => {
        // handle success or failure
    });
}
```

Then when you want to get the score with the tag just cast the **IScore** to **PlayGamesScore** like so:

```
PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.LoadScores(lId,
        leaderboardStart,
        scoresToDisplay,
        leaderboardType,
        leaderboardTimeSpan,
        (LeaderboardScoreData data) => {

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Scores.Length; i++)
            {
                //Just cast the IScore to PlayGamesScore :)
                PlayGamesScore score = (PlayGamesScore) data.Scores[i];

                float scoreValue = score.value;
                string tag = score.metaData;

                //store them and do what you want with them

            }
        }
);
```

I Hope this will help someone.

Comment: You sir made my day. Thank you